# Which solid fuel is optimal for light rocket?

Tags: rockets, solid-fuel, amateur-rocketry

I am in search of comparatively cheap and powerful enough solid fuel. I've found rocket candy, but is it enough to reach 1km altitude?

(My aim is a 2 metre high rocket with 0.5kg of payload.)

Comment: You should read the [help center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before asking question. The title should be specific and reflect your question (something like "where can I find references about solid fuel for home made sounding rockets?") and you may go more directly to the point (this is a Q&A site, not a forum)